# How to increase row height of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to change the height of the rows in a textarea?
My textarea has a height of 138px and it has 8 rows.
In Chrome everything looks fine.
But in Mozilla it doesn't look very good.

Just to be clear, I'm not talking about the height of the textarea. I'm talking about the height of the rows in that textarea.

Comment: Do you **explicitly** define the `line-height` and `font-size` and `padding` for your textarea?

Comment: well if you increase the height no rows will automatically increase, it just a way to do it with either html or css

Comment: just as NOX wrote, line-height and font-size should do the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to increase the height of *individual rows* of the textarea, then use the `line-height` CSS property:

```
textarea { line-height: 200%; }
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3nTz/))

Comment: Nice.. +1 for this and the live fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these plugins.These are  a nice plugins

[TextAreaExpander demonstration](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html) and [jQuery Elastic](http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)